# SLAM with one camera

Tags: slam, navigation, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

could i use SLAM with one camera only?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9091/slam-with-one-camera/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-02-19**:
"feasability" is not your only concern

you got stereo systems that use the depth of each pixels (from intel realsense) and yet these system sometimes fail to SLAM with 100% accuracy

so I doubt one camera will give you  reliable results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible, but a bit more complicated than using two cameras.  You are essentially using parallax in time (the camera position at one instant, and then the camera position at the next instant) to do feature recognition and localization.

Two resources for this come to mind:

1. [SLAM with a Single Camera](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/davison_cml2002.pdf), Davison 2002.  I think that he has a bit more information on his own [personal website](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Eajd/).
2. MPRT's [kinect-3d-slam](http://www.mrpt.org/Application:kinect-3d-slam).  I believe that this is also using the point cloud capabilities of the Kinect in addition to the vision data.  ROS source code is available on their website, though, so it might be a good place to start work.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-02-17**:
Thank you for very detailed answer!

**Comment by [KOMODO](https://answers.ros.org/users/45642/komodo/) on 2020-06-29**:
links are death

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be interested in Hauke Strasdat's work:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ScaViSLAM

It's not released yet, but should be soon.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-02-17**:
Great video! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

And also [RGBD-6D-SLAM](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM) (for kinect), as well as [MonoSLAM](http://www.mrpt.org/node/94) (for a normal camera)

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also look at:

- [FABMAP](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Emobile/wikisite/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Software.FABMAP)
- [PTAM](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Egk/PTAM/)
- [Scenelib](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Eajd/Scene/)

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2